# Text is displayed in bold in IE 8

Tags: text, internet-explorer-8, bold

All the text on my website appears in bold in IE 8. The other browsers such as IE 9, Chrome and FF show bold only where specified. Is there an IE 8 specific fix that I can use?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Maybe is a problem with your source code, please, share it.

Comment: Can you provide a link to the page?

Comment: I narrowed down the issue to the custom font we are using. We are using typekit's myriad pro condensed font on our site, which is turning all the text in to bold. I still don't have a fix.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [HTML conditionals.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537512%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) You can target ie-8 and add a css file with a specific rule.